# "page has not updated" or "page has not been updated"

Tags: tense, passive-voice, headlinese

Which one is correct?

> page has not updated

or

> page has not been updated.

Comment: Both are equally valid and correct: The page has not updated. The page has not been updated. -- Welcome to the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "update" transitive or intransitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65955/is-update-transitive-or-intransitive)

Comment: Any chance this might get moved to ell instead of being dismissed?

Comment: For me, these two phrases have different meanings.  The second phrase means that a *human being* has not posted an update to the page yet.  On the other hand, I could use the first phrase in the following situation, as an example: Say I post something to the web, refresh the page, and do not see my update yet.  Why?  Because there is a delay behind the scenes, at the *software* level.  A good example of that is the posting of Comments on StackExchange.  I write a comment, I hit "Add Comment," and then there is a short delay before the comment is visible on the web (even if I refresh the page).

Answer (score 2):

There are slight nuances to the different words. Both implicitly place "blame" and the nuance indicates where.

> The page has not updated.

This places the "blame" on the page or the system itself. It's pretty neutral. "Oh! the page hasn't updated. We've done what we ought, but the page hasn't kept up."

> The page has not been updated.

This places the "blame" on the content administrator. It is a little more apologetic. "Oh! we didn't update this page. It might be that we don't have anything new to say or we just weren't able to get around to it."

Which makes more sense? In the future, this would be a better fit for [the UX SE site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I think both should have a "the" in front of them. However both should be correct. I hope I helped. :)

Comment: Deletions (eg of articles) are common and acceptable in some registers (conversational; headlinese; terse instructional) (but only where clarity is not compromised).

Comment: Looks like a terse onscreen help msg.